# binding multiple properties to a textfield label in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, web, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to bind a string containing multiple values to a textfield in vuetify. I wrote the following code but it gives me the properties as string.

```
<div v-if="textField">
      <v-text-field
      :value="'Our client, {{this.name}}, is {{this.age}} years old.'"
      outline
      readonly
      >
</v-text-field>
</div>
```

The output is:

```
Our client, {{this.name}}, is {{this.age}} years old.
```

Eventhough I want to get *this.name* and *this.age* values that are *John* and *32* something like this:

```
Our client, John, is 32 years old.
```

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) directly in the template as:

```
<v-text-field
  :value="`Our client, ${name}, is ${age} years old.`"
  outline
  readonly
  >
```

Also notice [*Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes). That is, `{{}}` won't work for attributes.

Comment: I still receive the string `Our client, ${this.name}, is ${this.age} years old.` as the result.

Comment: Are you using backticks ` around the string? Notice it's not a single quote.

Answer (score 2):

Use a computed field.

```
{
  computed: {
    textFieldMsg() {
     return `Our client, ${this.name}, is ${this.age} years old.`;
  },
}
```

HTML

```
<v-text-field
  :value="textFieldMsg"
  outline
  readonly
  >
```

Also, depending on what you're trying to do with the text field will determine which solution is best for you. Are the values of `this.name` and `this.age` changing depending on other input fields? Is this just static content for the life of the page? Etc...

Comment: I still receive the string `Our client, ${this.name}, is ${this.age} years old.` as the result

Comment: Then there must be something else going on in your code. Hard to debug without seeing the javascript.

Comment: Was using single quote instead of backticks, thanks buddy :)